# Error "1038 Out of sort memory, consider increasing sort buffer size

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

In symfony2, doctrine2, I have a query which triggers an error :

```
Error "1038 Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size
```

The query :

```
$queryBuilder = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('object')
    ->leftJoin('object.objectCategory', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('object.medias', 'm')
    ->leftJoin('object.recipients', 'r')
    ->leftJoin('object.answers', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('object.tags', 't')
    ->leftJoin('object.user', 'u')
    ->leftJoin('object.votes', 'v')
    ->leftJoin('object.comments', 'comments')
    ->leftJoin('v.user', 'vuser')
    ->addSelect('c, t, v, u')
    ->groupBy('object, c, t, v, u')
    ->where('object.isVisible = :isVisible')
    ->orderBy('object.createdAt', 'DESC')
    ->setParameter('isVisible', true)
    ->addSelect('SUM(v.value) AS HIDDEN vote_value')
    ->orderBy('vote_value', 'DESC')
    ;
```

If I omit the group by, it runs just fine.
If I add select and group by less elements, it runs fine also but then I have more subqueries launched in my twig templates.

How can I either optimize this query to not have the error OR get rid of the error by allocating more memory (ideally just for this query) ?

Comment: Well, I got rid of the issue by removing the user from the addselect. it was not impacting the number of queries. below answer should be ok too.

Answer (score 78):

**Just run mysql query**

```
SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size = 256000000 // It'll reset after server restart
```

**To set permanent**

**Edit below file and add**

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

sort_buffer_size = 256000000

sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: `[mysqld]`
`sort_buffer_size = 256000000`  
for MySQL 8 standar configuration

Comment: Thanks Diego de la Riva. I had a pre-mysql 8 version installed on Ubuntu before so the headers in the config files in `/etc/mysql/` and `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` and `/etc/mysql/conf.d/` all had headers 
`[mysql]`
so it had to be changed to 
`[mysqld] sort_buffer_size = 256000000`

Comment: It works, but try to set permanent doesn't work!

Answer (score 67):

There's an outstanding [issue with MySQL](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103225) which causes this error when trying to sort on a table with a json column.  It looks like it impacts MySQL >= 8.0.18.  As of my reply here, the team is still considering whether this is a bug or not.  Please provide feedback on that thread if you're impacted by this.

While increasing the buffer size *can* be a solution here, IMO it really shouldn't be necessary as even ordering by the numeric primary key on a table with a json column can cause this issue.

In my experience, tweaking the buffer size isn't very reliable as the buffer size is relative to the length of the contents in the json column, so while it may solve the immediate issue, if your data set grows it'll need to be tweaked again.

Comment: Fixed in MySQL 8.0.28

Comment: It sounds like `TEXT` and `BLOB` columns can trigger this too.

Comment: Bug is still present in MySQL 8.0.29

Comment: After reading the linked issue: I'm not sure it is yet fixed to everyone's satisfaction, but one of the comments suggested adding an explicit index that exactly matches the order criteria, and that fixed the problem for me on MySQL 8.0.23 (host RDS Serverless V2).

Comment: I have an `ORDER BY` on the primary key column. With the fix in 8.0.28, it works fine if only a few columns are contained by the selection. But if I select all columns, the issue still occurs.

Comment: Although adding an index on the sorting column helped me in many occasions. However, in my current experience, running a SQL query selecting only the target JSON column while sorting causes the error despite the index on the sorting column. When I select all columns, the problem disappears. I filtered the columns and identified the minimum set. There was only one column that I had to always include in order to guarantee no errors. It's not the ID, nor the primary key, but the only column I had `LONGTEXT`. I know it's non-sense but thought sharing might help.

Comment: This problem is biting us in 2024 in Mysql 8.0.32 doing "select *" on a table with a JSON column and sorting strictly on a non-JSON column. As far as I can tell, the Mysql team closed issue #103225 as "documentation" and said, go pound sand (and increase your sort buffer size). Super extra infuriating.

Answer (score 34):

You probably need to increase the buffer size of mysql in the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, something like:

```
[mysqld]
sort_buffer_size=256k
```

Comment: See http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2010/05/09/how-to-tune-mysqls-sort_buffer_size/ ... by the way: I'm a beginner as well ;)

Comment: @Trinimon:- Indeed the idea is to increase the value of `sort_buffer_size`. Good link. :)

Comment: I've read there are cases when you can modify this parameter for a single query. do you know how ? (because it would impact performance in cases when it's not needed)

Comment: [`PDO::exec("set sort_buffer_size=bytes")`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

Comment: Try to avoid changing this config value according to mysql documentation. I could fix it converting old tables from myISAM to InnoDB.

Comment: sort_buffer_size=256k or 256M?

Answer (score 20):

So the answer is almost never to increase the buffer size (and to avoid touching the default settings in MySQL in general), but to review the quality of the query and/or to add an index to the column(s) you are running frequent queries against !!!

Syntax:

```
CREATE INDEX [index name] ON [table name]([column name]);
```

DOC:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: So basically what you want to do is create an index on the columns you are sorting by using `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using the docker mysql container add the follow setting in docker-compose.yml:

```
db:
    image: mysql:8
    command: --sort_buffer_size=512K
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case what actually helped without increasing the sort buffer size was to create indexes for the fields that I was ordering on. I'm not sure if it would work when joining tables but it will work when trying to order a single table which is very large.

Comment: Would probably help indexing the fields used for join. In MsSQL I'd look at explain plan.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like selecting columns with large json data can cause this error. I had  json column with html page inside and fixed the error by removing it from select statement.

Comment: I don't think it's "just" JSON data; I had a small union of two SELECTs in which each select included a term like 'a long text string' AS COLUMN1. In one case the 'a long text string' was 186k (characters, not bytes) - if I inspected that string in PHP and truncated it before including it in the SELECT, I avoided the memory issue (and didn't materially affect my results in this particular situation)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my laravel application, mysql is running in docker.

I have created folders

mkdir /home/user/mysql

mkdir /home/user/mysql/config

mkdir /home/user/mysql/mysql-data

nano /home/user/mysql/config/my.conf

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names = 1
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password 
bind-address=0.0.0.0
sort_buffer_size = 256000000
```

nano /home/user/mysql/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
    - ./config/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
    - "3334:3306"
    restart: always
```

nano /home/user/mysql/.env

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345
MYSQL_USER=admin
MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345
```

cd /home/user/mysql

docker-compose up -d

The problem has been solved