# Mysql2::Error: Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size using docker-compose.yml

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-workbench

Hi I'm building a rails app and I imported lots of data and inserted into the database. Some tables are okay and some tables have some errors that says out of sort memory.

**SQL ERROR**

```
Mysql2::Error: Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size
```

How do you increase server sort buffer size using the `docker-compose.yml` command?

I've tried this one:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command:
      - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      - --innodb-buffer-pool-size=402653184
```

I did add this command:

```
--innodb-buffer-pool-size=402653184
```

but I'm still getting the same error that it is out of memory. Is there any way to increase the buffer size using the `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "1038 Out of sort memory, consider increasing sort buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575835/error-1038-out-of-sort-memory-consider-increasing-sort-buffer-size)

Comment: I've updated my post I'm using docker as my environment setup.

Comment: Your buffer pool size is tiny, but its a fixed global size and the error is regarding a connection/session buffer that is required to be increased to complete the query.  While setting `-- sort_buffer_size=XXXX` is possible globally, that will translate to every connection getting this increased size might solve your problem, its also possible correct indexing on the table that maps to the SQL query  being performed will eliminate the need for this and make the query faster. Can you show what the SQL was that caused this error and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for those involved.

Comment: how do you set `sort_buffer_size=XXXX` in the `docker-compose.yml`? is it possible to do it like this `sort_buffer_size=1G`? @danblack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out when I've tested this, this resolves my error in the `mysql container` in docker.

Add this command in `docker-compose.yml` under your `db` services to increase your memory.

```
--sort_buffer_size=1073741824
```

To remove the error when your application is running on docker.

```
Error "1038 Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size
```

Note that `1073741824` is equal to bytes and will result to `1GB` memory allocation.

Comment: 1GB memory allocation _per session_!

Answer (score 2):

First thing, `402653184 (byte)` which is around 400 MB, if you are not sure about this memory limit then increase a bit more

```
    command:
      - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      - --innodb-buffer-pool-size=1G
```

And then verify the changes inside your container.

```
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024;
#it should return 1GB
```

Also, there is a possibility that something else causing the issue, you can check CPU, memory and slow query logs

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

you can then analyse the output base on current buffer pool size

```
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 412090368
Dictionary memory allocated 380237
Buffer pool size   24576
Free buffers       23618
Database pages     954
Old database pages 372
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
```

[MySQL optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-optimization.html)

Comment: I have updated my command and I still get an error about the `server sort buffer size` I think its got to do with the `sort buffer size` @Adiii